# Code duplication anaysis in IntelliJ and source generation

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-duplication

I have three Java classes that implement an `Iterable` interface. Two of them have the exact same implementation for their `iterator()` methods, which causes IntelliJ to flag the code as duplicated.

[image: The code duplication soft warning yielded by IntelliJ]

Since I'm using Java 8, I could push the implementation as a "default" at the level of the interface, but that would require also adding private fields on the interface which really gives out more information than is necessary, even if it were possible (I'm new to Java 8 so I'm not sure whether Java 8 also allows you to declare or even initialize fields at the level of the interface). Even if I were to do that, there will be more classes implementing the common interface with different implementations for `iterator()`.

I have found [this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/analyzing-duplicates.html#dup) towards the IntelliJ documentation that says the following:

> To do that, select the check box **Ignore duplicated code in sources marked as generated** in the inspection settings page:[...]

Unfortunately, despite the fact that this checkbox does indeed appear in my inspection settings page:

[image]

The problem still persists after checking that checkbox. I'm not entirely sure what "generated sources" means in the link that I posted above and I'm looking for some assistance.

For what it's worth, I'm running IntelliJ 2017.1 Ultimate Edition.

Comment: `Generated` means automatically generated sources that reside in the roots marked as *Generated Sources*. Why do you think it should apply to your code? If you don't want this inspection for certain code fragments, just [suppress it](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/suppressing-inspections.html).

Comment: Ah, that link was somewhat helpful, however it should also be noted that for this particular error, intelliJ was not giving me the classic light bulb popup way of suppressing the warning is not possible, see https://www.dropbox.com/home/Screenshots?preview=inspectionCannotBeSuppressed.png. See the response below for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I used @CrazyCoder's response above and found out and ran a so-called "code analysis", as offered by IntelliJ, and found the following functionality:

[image]

Clicking on "disable inspection" does solve the problem at hand, however in general this is undesirable. I would really like it if I could somehow only keep this "weak warning" for same-source file methods. If I duplicate code across `public` class definitions, it's usually because I know what I'm doing, as in this case.